# Can ext: Window be constrained in framelike Master markup?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, ext.net

I am building an MVC4-Ext.net application with static navigation. I have succeeded in binding the Navigation in the Master-Page and making the project run error-free. Now I want to use a `<ext:Window/>` inside the "Main Content", which is a `<ext:Panel region="Center">` from my Master-Page.

I tried to go:

```
 <ext:Window runat="server" Constrain="true" Width="600" />
```

But the window still was movable out of the "MainContent".
I also tried introducing a

```
 <ext:Viewport runat="server" ID="InnerViewPort" Layout="FitLayout">
```

To constrain the Window, but that also did not work.

I'd like to refrain from using a "Constraining Window" to keep me from having to set my Content measurements as fixed values.

These attempts are in my `<asp:Content ID="Content" ContentPlaceHolderID="Main">` who is inside the Centered Panel of the Master Page Viewport

I have some Base.Master file having simplified markup like this:

```
<ext:Viewport ID="CompleteView" runat="server">
   <Items>
      <ext:Panel runat="server" Region="North" ID="TopBar" />
      <ext:Panel runat="server" Region="West" ID="Navigation" />
      <ext:Panel runat="server Region="Center" ID="MainContent" />
          <Content>
              <asp:ContentPlaceholder ID="Main" runat="server" />
          </Content>
      </ext:Panel>
   </Items>
</ext:Viewport>
```

I now want the window to be constrained inside the `MainContent` Panel when I load my View to Placeholder `Main`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A litte bit of reworking and excluding Master-Pages brought me to the pont described in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15785240/load-asp-mvc-view-with-ext-panel-loader).

Loading a View with an ext.net.Window component, that is set to `constrain="true"` does really constrain the window, given you are in `loadMode="IFrame"`

Answer (score 0):

Based upon your description, I think the following sample demonstrates the scenario.

You can set .Constrain="true" on the  and set the .RenderTo property to the .ID of the Container you want the Window to Constrain to.

**Example**

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" %> 

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head runat="server">
    <title>Ext.NET Example</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form runat="server">
        <ext:ResourceManager runat="server" />

        <ext:Viewport runat="server" Layout="BorderLayout">
            <Items>
                <ext:Panel
                    runat="server"
                    Title="Example"
                    Region="West"
                    Width="350"
                    Collapsible="true"
                    />
                <ext:Panel 
                    id="Panel1" 
                    runat="server" 
                    Title="Center" 
                    Region="Center"
                    />
            </Items>
        </ext:Viewport>
        <ext:Window 
            ID="Window1" 
            runat="server" 
            Title="Window"
            Constrain="true"
            RenderTo="Panel1"
            />
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: would be glad if it had worked, but it seems i need to clarify the question, see updated question please