# Load ASP-MVC View with Ext.Panel loader

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asynchronous, ext.net

I have following layout, related to the one i am describing in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15769010/can-extwindow-be-constrained-in-framelike-master-markup)

```
<ext:Viewport runat="server">
  <Items>
    <ext:Panel Region="North" runat="server" ID="TopBar" />
    <ext:Panel Region="West" runat="server" ID="Nav" >
       <Items>
          <ext:Button runat="server" ID="loaderComponentFooBar">
             <DirectEvents>
                <Click OnEvent="loadFooBar" />
             </DirectEvents>
          </ext:Button>
          //Some more Buttons each with his own loader Function in Code-Behind
       </Items>
    </ext:Panel>
    <ext:Panel runat="server" Region="center" ID="MainPanel" />
  </Items>
</ext:Viewport>
```

on Button-Click i now want to load my View @ "/Foo/Bar/" to the `MainPanel`

How can i achieve this in CodeBehind?

I already tried:

```
public void loadFooBar(object sender, DirectEventArgs e)
{
   MainPanel.Loader.Url = "/Foo/Bar/"; //Throws null reference Exception

   MainPanel.Loader.Url = "~/Foo/Bar/"; // same as above

   MainPanel.Loader.GetUrlByRoute("Foo/Bar/"); //again the same

   MainPanel.Loader.LoadContent("/Foo/Bar/");

   //and after each of these attempts except the last went:
   MainPanel.Loader.Mode = LoadMode.Frame;
   MainPanel.Loader.LoadMask.ShowMask = false;
   MainPanel.Loader.LoadContent();
}
```

Just by the way, i am using aspx-web-application views

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you should not use a page's code behind for DirectEvents' handlers. It is going out of the MVC concept. You should refer a controller's actions.

Here is an example.

**Example View**

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage" %>

<%@ Register Assembly="Ext.Net" Namespace="Ext.Net" TagPrefix="ext" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head runat="server">
    <title>Ext.Net.MVC v2 Example</title>
</head>
<body>
    <ext:ResourceManager runat="server" />

    <ext:Viewport runat="server" Layout="BorderLayout">
        <Items>
            <ext:Panel runat="server" Region="West" Width="100">
                <Items>
                    <ext:Button 
                        runat="server" 
                        Text="Load View 1" 
                        DirectClickUrl=<%# Url.Action("LoadView1") %>
                        AutoDataBind="true" />

                    <ext:Button 
                        runat="server" 
                        Text="Load View 2" 
                        DirectClickUrl=<%#Url.Action("LoadView2") %>
                        AutoDataBind="true" />
                </Items>
            </ext:Panel>

            <ext:Panel ID="MainPanel" runat="server" Region="Center">
                <Loader runat="server" Mode="Frame" AutoLoad="false">
                    <LoadMask ShowMask="true" />
                </Loader>
            </ext:Panel>
        </Items>
    </ext:Viewport>
</body>
</html>
```

**Example Controller**

```
using System.Web.Mvc;
using Ext.Net;
using Ext.Net.MVC;

namespace Work2MVC.Controllers
{
    public class AspxController : Controller
    {
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            return View();
        }

        public ActionResult View1()
        {
            return View();
        }

        public ActionResult View2()
        {
            return View();
        }

        public ActionResult LoadView1()
        {
            Panel p = X.GetCmp<Panel>("MainPanel");
            p.LoadContent(Url.Action("View1"));

            return this.Direct();
        }

        public ActionResult LoadView2()
        {
            Panel p = X.GetCmp<Panel>("MainPanel");
            p.LoadContent(Url.Action("View2"));

            return this.Direct();
        }
    }
}
```

Also you can initiate a load request on client side via JavaScript. Then you avoid an additional request.